# Flutter Scaffold(appBar: AppBar()) not working 'const' error

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar, scaffold

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('I am Rich'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

this is my code and there is showing "the constructor called is not a constructor"

Error message-

```
lib/main.dart:8:17: Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.
Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'.
        appBar: AppBar(
                ^^^^^^

tried adding 'const' before scaffold
```

I am sorry for the silly question. I am just a beginner. can't find the solution anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

To be a bit more precise: AppBar doesn't have a const constructor, so you can't use the const keyword. However, Text does have a const constructor, so you can (should) use const for that one.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('I am Rich'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'const' before MaterialApp. It should work fine.

the correct code should be

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('I am Rich'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: can you use format tool, it will look better

Answer (score 0):

Just remove const

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('I am Rich'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).